# Python merge multiple txt files

Tags: python, text, merge

I tried to merge multiple TXT-files in a folder with this code but it is not working:

```
import os,shutil
path = "C:/Users/user/Documents/MergeFolder"
f=open(path + "/fileappend.txt","a")
for r,d,fi in os.walk(path):
     for files in fi:
         if files.endswith(".txt"):                         
              g=open(os.path.join(r,files))
              shutil.copyfileobj(g,f)
              g.close()
f.close()
```

Anyone has an idea?

Comment: its not working... can you specify the details,, does your destination get overwritten

Comment: no nothing was overwritten or generated for me too

Comment: I'm confused seeing both `/tmp` and `C:\users` in the same code. What's the system you're in? Also, write `r"C:\Users..."` instead, to prevent escaping.

Comment: Ok. Changed the path and I get a huge TXT-file where all content from all TXT-files is merged but it should only merge TXT-files from path.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: you're creating `fileappend.txt` inside `path`, while writing to it. Depending on when the writes are flushed to disk, you may be trying to read the file that you're appending to. This would cause, well, lots of weirdness. Consider not placing `fileappend.txt` inside `path`, or else just moving it there when you're done.

You can write your code more neatly as:

```
with open(os.path.join(path, "fileappend.tmp"), "a") as dest:
    for _, _, filenames in os.walk(path):
        for filename in fnmatch.filter(filenames, "*.txt"):
            with open(filename) as src:
                shutil.copyfileobj(src, dest)
os.rename(os.path.join(path, "fileappend.tmp"), "fileappend.txt")
```

Comment: Hi, I tried your code but got this: NameError: global name 'fnmatch' is not defined

Comment: You need to `import fnmatch`.

Comment: Now I got this: IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'fileappend.txt' but the file exists without content.

Answer (score 0):

you can use cat(shell command)

```
cat 1.txt>>2.txt
```

in python, you can use os.system() to use shell command