# how to write multiple xml files(desired information only) into one master text file in python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook, filesystems

i have about 3 to 4k xml files with some information.i want to write the desired information of all files into a master text file.

i have jupyter notebook.and i have tried the example of concatinating the example of merging multiple text files into one text file.but i need to write multiple xml files into one text file.

```
import pandas as pd 
# pd.read_csv creates dataframes 

df1 = pd.read_csv('D:\python\data_files\data_files\emp_1.txt') 
df2 = pd.read_csv('D:\python\data_files\data_files\emp_2.txt') 
df3 = pd.read_csv('D:\python\data_files\data_files\emp_3.txt') 

frames = [df1, df2, df3] 

# concat function concatenates the frames 
result = pd.concat(frames) 
# to_csv function writes output to file 
result.to_csv('D:\\python\\data_files'
            '\\target_file\\master.txt', encoding ='utf-8', index = False)
```

i want to write multiple xml files into one master text file.

Comment: In your question description, you are quoting XML file but in your example, you are doing `pd.read_csv` How come?

Answer (score 0):

Python does not care about what kind of UTF-8 formatted files you want to merge. So just have a look at this tutorial to merge text files: [Python merge multiple txt files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13525847/python-merge-multiple-txt-files)